# How do I use an If-Else to do certain things if the days of the week are set of days?

Tags: shell-script, shell, regular-expression

I have a requirement that if a day of the week is either Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday , perform certain scripts otherwise I don't do anything.

```
if [[ $(date '+%a') == "Mon" && $(date '+%a') == "Tue" && $(date '+%a') == "Wed" ]]
then
echo "PERFORM TASK"
else
echo "DONT DO ANYTHING"
 fi
```

I'm getting 
DONT DO ANYTHING

Which is wrong. because today date is "Monday".. so I was expecting to get "PERFORM TASK"... If I only do just Monday only, is working ...`if [[ $(date '+%a') == "Mon" ]]` .. is when I add the other days , isn't working....what am I doing wrong? please help.

Comment: `&&` means *and*. `||` is used for *or* conditional.

Answer (score 4):

```
case "$(date +%a)" in
   Sun)
     handle_sunday_stuff
     break
     ;;
   Tue|Thu)
     handle_tuesday_thursday_stuff
     break
     ;;
   Wed)
     handle_wednesday_stuff
     break
     ;;
   *)
     echo "Nothing to do today"
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: This is, I would say, _the_ way to do this in a script. I don't know what _I_ was thinking...

Comment: Not as succinct as a one-liner, but definitely more readable and portable to other similar purposes (:

Answer (score 2):

You're asking

```
if today is Monday AND today is Tuesday AND ...
```

which clearly cannot be true. The `&&` is an AND condition operator. You probably want `||`, which is the OR condition operator.

```
today=$(date +'%a')
if [[ $today == "Mon" || $today == "Tue" || $today == "Wed" ]]
then
    echo "PERFORM TASK"
else
    echo "DON'T DO ANYTHING"
fi
```

As an efficiency consideration I have moved the `date` command outside the `if...` condition so that it's executed only once. (This also avoids a potential race condition across Sunday/Monday or Wednesday/Thursday midnight.)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `&&` rather than `||` in your condition, which means that to get the `PERFORM TASK` output, the day of the week has to be *all* those days.

Instead:

```
day="$( date +"%a" )"

if [[ "$day" =~ ^(Mon|Tue|Wed)$ ]]; then
    echo "PERFORM TASK"
else
    echo "DON'T DO ANYTHING"
fi
```

(This solution assumes `bash` or `ksh93` or any other shell that does regular expressions in this way with `=~`)

Comment: @roaima Yes, there are very few ways to do this. I'm using a regular expression though, while you rely on string comparisons.